# JSpinner Source?

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I have a class with two JSpinner objects in them, x and y.
I have one change Listener which is added to both.
can someone tell me how I can implement my change listener so that the listener can tell the difference between the two objects.
e.g. Pseudocode:

```
if(source equals x)
    do this
else if(source equals y)
    do that
```

Thanks guys,

Comment: A better way is to use anonymous class

Answer (score 3):

You can simply use an anonymous class to implement the listener for each spinner

For example if you want to implement change listener to x, you can do something like:

```
x.addChangeListener(new ChangeListener()
{
   public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
   {
   }
});
```

and same thing for y

Answer (score 2):

It's more prudent (as Ali has pointed out, +1) to use a single listener per control where possible.  It isolates the event/action and makes it generally easier to read and make sense of...

If you can't see yourself using this, then every `EventObject` has a `getSource` method which is a reference to the control which raised the event...

```
public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e)
{
    if (e.getSource() == xControl) {
        // xControl updated
    } else if (e.getSource() == yControl) {
        // yControl updated
    }
}
```

Comment: I did try implementing your solution but I then get a problem when I want to get the value of the JSpinner.

Comment: Presumably, you need to cast the source back to a `JSpinner`